# fb login popup block

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, fbml, fbconnect

I am making using fb login feature but problem comming to me is that whenever I click on the fb login button before page media loading is completed, it blocks the popup for fb login but if I click on fblogin after a second passed to loading event it works

Here is the function I am using:

```
function fb_login() {
var email='';
console.log(loginClassbackQueue);
// console.log('user wants to login with fb');
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if(response.status!='connected'){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            // console.log(response);
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // console.log('user logged in successfully');
                // console.log(response);
                email = update_f_data_login(response);
                $('#fb_login_popup, #popup_overlay').hide();
                // loginme(email);
                } 
            else {
                    loginClassbackQueue = [];
                // console.log('user failed to login');
                }
                // console.log('fb login completed successfully');
            }, {scope:"email,user_birthday,user_likes,user_location,friends_likes,publish_actions"}
        );
        }
    else{
    // console.log('logged in and connected');
    email = update_f_data_login(response);
    $('#fb_login_popup, #popup_overlay').hide();
    }

});

}
```

The same action when I do on this site http://fab.com/ it open popups always never block a popup.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You cannot call `FB.login` from the callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`.

Browsers tend to block popup windows of the popup is not spawned as an immediate result of a user's click action.

Because `FB.getLoginStatus` does an `ajax` call and you call `FB.login` on it's response, the popup that would open as a result of this call is **blocked**.

A solution to your problem would be to call `FB.getLoginStatus` on page load and use the response inside your `fb_login()` method.

Comment: That solution only works if the user is logged in to Facebook when the page loads. Fails otherwise.

Comment: Not exactly correct. It's perfectly fine to call `FB.login` from the callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`, and in fact in many cases it is exactly the right thing to do. You just need to be confident that the login status has _already been loaded_. The most obvious way is to specify `status: true` in the options object of `FB.init`, but other ways are to use `FB.getLoginStatus`, `FB.login`, or `FB.ui` (technically all of these options use `FB.ui`) and that async process has to complete. You should also make sure not to specify `true` for the second parameter, as in `FB.getLoginStatus(..., true);`.

Comment: @vvo the calls are not nested.  one would check the status on page load.  once a user clicks a button to log in to your site, then you will know if you need to call FB.login, or continue on a different path in your application logic

Comment: @AndrewF this is by far the most useful comment EVER on the Facebook JS SDK login / share issues I had for days and days now. Your comment no not using `true` as the second parameter to `FB.getLoginStatus` plus using the `display: "iframe"` for the share dialog fixed my troubles (except for when you logout from FB after you opened your website; any idea on that scenario?).

Comment: add to this, the call FB.login must be the first call from the click event. any call stack between two would result in "popup block"

Comment: I was calling the fb login from a success response of AJAX, I fixed it with the answer here. Thank you

Comment: great tip from AndrewF

Answer (score 41):

It's perfectly fine to call `FB.login` from the callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`, as long as you are confident that the login status has *already been loaded* internally. To do this, use one of these:

- `FB.init({..., status: true, ... })`.
- `FB.getLoginStatus(...)`
- `FB.login(...)`
- `FB.ui(...)`

Technically all of these options use `FB.ui`. The async process has to complete, which could take a few seconds. As long as you have already used one of the methods above to make a cross-domain call with FB, and that async process has completed, getting the login status will not make an async call, and the popup will not be blocked.

You should also make sure *not* to specify `true` for the second parameter, as in `FB.getLoginStatus(..., true);`.

Comment: Setting FB.getLoginStatus(..., true) second parameter to true will invoke popup blocker in desktop Chrome; only use it in case of special handing with URL callback login to force cache (eg: for Facebook login in Chrome iOS).

Comment: Hence "you should also make sure not to specify true".

Comment: Thanks @AndrewF by passing true in FB.init I can use getLoginStatus as callback function and it does not block popup

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you set **status** to ***true***, this will fixed popup blocker issue.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5', // use graph api version 2.5
    status     : true // set this status to true, this will fixed popup blocker issue
  });
```

Comment: This worked for me ... the documentation for the status option says that it Determines whether the current login status of the user is freshly retrieved on every page load. If this is disabled, that status will have to be manually retrieved using .getLoginStatus(). Defaults to false.
Though I got a little idea on what it actually does ... works irrespective whether the user is logged in fb or not...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it kick my head for 3 days. I did stumble on the above mentioned solutions and they worked in Firefox and Edge but in Chrome not matter what ever i did i still got blocked left right and center.The other problem was when i called the function from a button press event the login dialog was not block but it didn't get any responses after the login dialog closes for further actions so i got stuck. So my solution is as follow, but you don't need to press the login in button it will redirect to the FB-login page without a button press event, and on return continue with all the other sdk steps. Just add this to your code and see if it helps, from there adjust according to your need

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);


            // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
            // app know the current login status of the person.
            // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
            // for FB.getLoginStatus().
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                document.getElementById('Image2').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('mail').style.display = "in-line";

                testAPI();
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
                window.alert("Faça login no facebook antes de continuar - Obrigado");
                window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth' +
                '?client_id=55215442252214521548' +
                '&scope=public_profile,email,user_friends' +
                '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
                document.getElementById('Image2').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('mail').style.display = "in-line";

            }
        }

        // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
        // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
        // code below.
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);

            });
        }
```