# Window.open not working on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling below jquery method to export the table details into PDF. PDF file is created in the java class while it is called and available in the path 
**C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\TestProj\PDFfiles**
and the JSP where im having this script is loacted at
**C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\TestProj\WEB-INF\jsp**
But window.open is not working. I can get the alert message of "PDF generation success ---"

Any idea? Please help.

```
function openPDF() {
        $.post("generatePDF", {action : "get"}, function(data) {
            if (data.returnStatus == "SUCCESS") {               
                alert("PDF generation success ---");
                var win = window.open('', 'fullscreen=no');
                win.location.href = '../../PDFfiles/TestPdf.pdf';
                win.focus(); 
                //window.open('../../PDFfiles/TestPdf.pdf', 'fullscreen=no');

            }
        }, 'json');     
    }
```

I have tried below snippet also but no use..

```
window.open('../../PDFfiles/ShopsListPdf.pdf', 'fullscreen=no');
```

Comment: Do you have a popup-blocker preventing the new window from opening?

Comment: What happens when you use the URL "/TestProj/PDFfiles/ShopsListPdf.pdf"?  The "WEB-INF" directory is special, and you can't navigate with ".." like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript window.open not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821009/javascript-window-open-not-working)

Comment: I tried your code in jsfiddle with Chrome and it works fine

Comment: popup-blocker is removed and still no use..

Comment: Tried with "/TestProj/PDFfiles/TestPdf.pdf" but not working

Answer (score 2):

`window.open` works only on user actions like `click` but if there is a delay after that it will be blocked by browser. delay like you have made in `ajax call`. So try to execute `window.open` asap after `click`

*Note:* sometimes when ajax call come too fast due to cache or something, the window.open may work, it happens to me lot of time, specially when I was trying to make a facebook login here the link when I posted a question [fb login popup block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559115/fb-login-popup-block)

Comment: when I call generatePDF, that class actually generates the PDF from the data from session and place the PDF in C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\TestProj\PDFfiles So it is like I need to open a pdf file from the folder.

Comment: then you can just make a button to `generate a pdf` and when done change the button text to `download it` and 2nd click on that can be use as window.open

Comment: or you can do that open a window with a page which have a code to generate the pdf on page load event and display